# decoding regex expression

Tags: regex

I'm trying to decode the following regex expression. For some reason, it doesn't work on my online decoder. Can anybody help me decrypt the following:

```
Regex r = new Regex("src=\"(?<src>[^\"]+)\"")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you say that? @h2000000 gave the answer below

Comment: the edit was not reloaded..my bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you're missing the last quotation symbol, but let's ignore that.

**Autopsy:**

```
src=\"(?<src>[^\"]+)\"
```

- `src=` - *The literal string `src=`*
- `\"` - *A literal quote (escaped to make sure the string doesn't terminate)*
- `(?<src>[^\"]+)`

  - A capturing group named `src` (`?<src>`) matching:
  - `[^\"]+` - Any character that *isn't* a `"` character, matched 1 to infinity times (`+`)
- `\"` - *A literal quote (escaped to make sure the string doesn't terminate)*

**[Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/5Sl_90JZJBnQxl0x):**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**In human words:**

With the string `<img src="picture.png" />` this will create a named capturing group named `src` containing `picture.png`.

**Regex limitations:**

If your image is created using single quotes (`<img src='picture.png' />`) this will not work correctly. In that case you can use something like:

```
src=(\"(?<src1>[^\"]+)\"|\'(?<src2>[^\']+)\')
                        ^
     DOUBLE QUOTES     OR      SINGLE QUOTES
```

that will match both (in either `src1` or `src2` depending on the quotation type).

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: thanks. added the missing "

Comment: If you're going to ignore the regex in string form, why do you escape the double qutation's ? That's not what is passed to the regex engine..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because your pattern was incorrect to begin with? I think this is what you wanted:

```
Regex r = new Regex("src=\"([^\"]+)\"")
```

This will capture `image.jpeg` in `src="image.jpeg"`.

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/hV6kH2/1)

Comment: you probably also want to check for single quotes here